# live reload on a Docker Angular project does not work?

Tags: angular, docker, livereload

the structure of the file :

```
/my-project
Dockerfile.ng
docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  project:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ng
    ports:
      - "4203:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
    volumes:
      - "/app/node_modules"
      - ".:/app"
      - ./my-project:/var/www/my-project
```

Dockerfile.ng

```
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /root/
COPY ./my-project /root/my-project
WORKDIR /root/my-project
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4203 49153
CMD npm run start-hr
```

/my-project/package.json

```json
...
    "start-hr": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --poll 500"
...
```

```
docker-compose build  
docker-compose up -d
```

http://localhost:4203/
The application launches.
I modify the code and the live reload does not work.
windows 10 - angular 11 - Docker 20

*locally, when I modify the code, I go to the docker container and the file is not modified.

I think there is a problem with the COPY command but I don't know how to solve it.*

Comment: Can you `npm run start-hr` from your host, ignoring this Docker setup entirely?

Comment: in local, it work. into host, port is already use

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your docker-compose file to the following:

```sh
version: "3.9"

services:
  project:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ng
    ports:
      - "4203:4200"
      - "49153:49153"
    volumes:
      - ./my-project:/root/my-project
```

Try changing your Dockerfile like below:

```sh
FROM node:12-alpine
WORKDIR /root/my-project
COPY ./my-project /root/my-project
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4203 49153
CMD npm run start-hr
```

Comment: eranga, it doesn't work.  -> page not found

Comment: I made a slight change to your dockerfile, could you try it?

Comment: no, still not :( .....  locally, when I modify the code, I go to the docker container and the file is not modified. I think there is a problem with the COPY command but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: But the app will run on the container with the earlier changes, right? No issues in app?

Comment: the application launches once. I modify the code locally and the application does not update. even if I press F5.

Comment: In local, if you start the app with `npm run start-hr` and if you do any changes would it reload automatically?

Comment: I removed some unnecessary volumes from docker-compose file. Can you try again?

Comment: now it works with /root   :).  
I deleted the containers, rebooted the pc.
I removed some unnecessary volumes
thanks for helping me.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct and helpful, could you upvote and accept it?